# Cronjob on PHP function

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to add a cron in **Ubuntu**. This cron will execute a function in **PHP** for **every 4 month**.

How could I do that?

Comment: `crontab -e`  opens up the crontab editor (see `man crontab` for more info)  then just add an entry for  `php your_file.php` to happen every 4 months

Answer (score 1):

First, Login to UNIX/Linux system.

Type the following command to enter cronjob:

```
$ crontab -e

Each cronjob has the following syntax:

# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
  *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

To get crontab to run a task every 10 minutes you could type as follow:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/command
```

OR

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/script
```

[Reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

Comment: `*/10` not 10 seconds ?

Comment: thank you for ur respons sir, but i cant make it to execute the function in the php file, how could i specify the function inside the php file?

Answer (score 0):

**Starting to Use Cron**

To use cron for tasks meant to run only for your user profile, add entries to your own user's crontab file. To edit the crontab file enter:

```
crontab -e
```

**Add below Cron Line**

```
30 03 01 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct * File Path
```

Comment: thank you for ur respons sir, but i cant make it to execute the function in the php file, how could i specify the function inside the php file?

Comment: that's a complete different question. You asked how to call a PHP-Script within a cronjob and this is your answer. We can't tell you how to call your function, you didn't even provide any code.